# Почему большинство требует React, а не Angular или VueJS

Tags: reactjs, frontend, angular

Полгода назад выбрал по собственным критериям VueJS - люблю его до сих пор.

---

Angular при пробах понравился. Сейчас ищу работу Frontend-разработчиком, опыт позволяет. Большинство требует React, Angular встречается реже, Vue вообще мало.

---

Я понимаю, что подводных камней может быть очень много. И уже в течении недели изучаю реактовский стэк. И все чаще задаюсь вопросом, почему выбирают его? Не хотелось бы изучать эти технологии, а потом осознать, что они мне не нравится.
Несколько вопросов:

---

У реакта кроме реактивных свойств есть что-то еще? Альтернатива v-model и ng-model в Angular и Vue?

---

Мобильная разработка у React Native такая же как с Angular+Phonegap или предоставляет большие возможности для подготовки к разработке проекта под мобильные устройства?

---

Вы считаете, что .bind() в фреймворках это нормально?

---

Какие есть плюсы, кроме JSX(и это совсем даже не плюс)?

Comment: Реакт - это не просто "реактивные свойства" и не альтернатива модели. Один из основных плюсов React / Redux именно в том, что в нем нет view model, повторяющей форму UI. Доизучайте до конца, включая redux, чтобы получить полную картину - и многие вопросы отпадут :)

Comment: Реакт старше, и его тащит уже заработанная популярность. Плюс, у него поддержка крупной компании, чего у Vue пока что нет. Более-менее объективные сравнения возможностей React и Vue можно легко найти в огромном кол-ве статей, TL;DR: разницы практически нет, она только в удобстве использования (тут уж более новая либа, естессно, превосходит). _«JSX(и это совсем даже не плюс)»_ - чертовски верно, +1  :)

Comment: как где-то тут писали раньше, хотя на jquery пиши, хоть на реакте, всё равно будет сидеть и фиксить баги